# magento 1.9 catalog price rules disappear in view page overnight

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I am running Magento 1.9.3. I made a price rule to give all customer group `25%` off on all products, and date is 7/25/2017 to 8/31/2017. I click the button "Save and Apply", the prices of all products run well.

[image]

But `catalog price rules` disappear in view page(Only view page) overnight.

I know this question already asked, for me `catalog price rules` working in list page but not working in view page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check **cron jobs** are working or not in your site, there are number of ways to check whether cron jobs are working or not, one way is installing [Aoe scheduler](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) Extension. Also make sure the server and magento site **timings** should be the same.

IF cron is working , than follow below link  :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night

Comment: Can you please explain what cron has to do with catalog price rules?

Comment: @YogeshTrivedi As `catalog Price rules` are `scheduled activities` to run periodically at certain times or dates , it must need `cron jobs` to work properly.....

Comment: Thanks for reply tried this code `$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);`. It working in localhost. But in live i won't working

Comment: @RameshS may be check your server time and magento time is same or not..... also in live , click on `apply catalog price rules` button and i guess you may need to wait until midnight to check whether its working or not......

Comment: @BabyinMagento:  If i click `apply catalog price rules` it's working. Actually every morning am `apply catalog price rules` manually. I think you are right, may be problem in server time. Wait i ll check and tell you. Your answer is useful so i i ll click `up vote` for your answer..